# find unique neighbour pairs between two point clouds in R

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, assignment-problem, r

Given two point clouds I want to find for each point from the first point cloud the nearest neighbour from the second point cloud. **Also, each pair of neighbours should be unique.** The solution was already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371485/11738400) for Python. However, I was wondering if a similar approach exists for R (I'd like to avoid the suggested `cvxpy` library from the Python solution which requires the `pyscipopt` library which again requires the installation of the `SCIP Optimization Suite`).

Some example code with two point clouds:

```
set.seed(666)

# Example data
px = runif(210, min = 0, max = 100)
py = runif(210, min = 0, max = 100)

pc1 = cbind(x = px[1:100], y = py[1:100])
pc2 = cbind(x = px[101:210], y = py[101:210])

plot(pc1, pch = 16, col = 1)
points(pc2, pch = 16, col = 2)

# Calculate distance matrix
# library(pdist)
# d = pdist(pc1, pc2)
# d = as.matrix(d)

# Find closest neighbour
library(FNN)
nn = get.knnx(pc2, pc1, k = 1)

for(i in 1:nrow(pc1)) lines(x = c(pc1[i,1], pc2[nn$nn.index[i,1],1]),
                            y = c(pc1[i,2], pc2[nn$nn.index[i,1],2]))
```

[image: Nearest neighbours for each point from Point Cloud 1 (black) to Point Cloud 2 (red) connected by a line. In this case, one point from Point Cloud 2 might be nearest to multiple points from Point Cloud 1.]

As shown in the image above, I'm capable of finding the nearest neighbour for each point from Point Cloud 1 (black) to Point Cloud 2 (red). Yet, multiple points from Point Cloud 2 are assigned to the same point from Point Cloud 1. Any idea how to find unique pairs with minimal overall distances instead?

Edit:

I tried another approach by finding the closest pair iteratively and removing that pair from the following queries:

```
# Approach 2:

pairs = matrix(NA, ncol = 4, nrow = nrow(pc1)) #storage for pairs
colnames(pairs) = c("x(pc1)", "y(pc1)", "x(pc2)", "y(pc2)")

pc2_copy = pc2 # copy of Point Cloud 2 which will shrink each iteration

for(i in 1:nrow(pc1)){
  nn = get.knnx(pc2_copy, pc1[i,,drop = FALSE], k = 1)
  pairs[i,1:2] = pc1[i,1:2,drop = FALSE]
  pairs[i,3:4] = pc2_copy[nn$nn.index[1,1],1:2,drop = FALSE]
  pc2_copy = pc2_copy[-c(nn$nn.index[1,1]),] #remove the corresponding point from the matrix
}

plot(pc1, pch = 16, col = 1)
points(pc2, pch = 16, col = 2)

for(i in 1:nrow(pairs)) lines(x = pairs[i,c(1,3)], y = pairs[i, c(2,4)])
```

[image]

While this gives me unique pairs, I don't believe this is anywhere near an ideal solution (in my real data example some distances are very little while others are immense with an obviously much better solution by eye).

A solution to this question has been provided on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73122788/11738400)